# Can AWS System Manager login as ec2-user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I have an EC2 instance that's typically used via manually sshing onto the box as `ec2-user`.  Over time the box has accrued various custom configurations such as docker config and git access to our private repositories.

Am trying to automate some commands on the box using AWS System Manager, but system manager logs in as `root`, which lacks the aforementioned configuration of `ec2-user`.  Is it possible to somehow login as `ec2-user` from system manager or change users while logged in?  Because the box has been customized over several months, its not obvious how to reconfigure from scratch (also don't have time to dive into).

Have tried changing user via `su ec2-user` to no avail.

*As a workaround*, I'm simply running SSH commands on the box directly eg

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/MYPEM.pem ec2-user@MYINSTANCE.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com "touch FOOFILE && git clone REPO"`

but this avoids system manager altogether and is undesirable.

Comment: That's not why `su` fails. Prefix commands that need to be ran as `ec2-user` with `sudo -u ec2-user`.

Comment: or `sudo su ec2-user` if that's more intuitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @jordanm for pointing me in the right direction.  I was able to switch to ec2-user afterall using using `runuser` command ([see more here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/))

```
runuser -l ec2-user -c {COMMAND}
```

for example

```
runuser -l ec2-user -c 'whoami && git pull'
```

I guess because AWS System Manger is already root, no additional password/auth requried to switch to ec2-user.